# When I submit my code in HackerRank, it failed in three test cases and showing that "Terminated due to timeout :(" .So how can I fix it?

Tags: java

**Here is the question**

You are given a phone book that consists of people's names and their phone number. After that you will be given some person's name as query. For each query, print the phone number of that person.

**Input Format**

The first line will have an integer  denoting the number of entries in the phone book. Each entry consists of two lines: a name and the corresponding phone number.

After these, there will be some queries. Each query will contain a person's name. Read the queries until end-of-file.

**Constraints**:
A person's name consists of only lower-case English letters and it may be in the format 'first-name last-name' or in the format 'first-name'. Each phone number has exactly 8 digits without any leading zeros.

1<=n<=100000

1<=Query<=100000

**Output Format**

For each case, print "Not found" if the person has no entry in the phone book. Otherwise, print the person's name and phone number. See sample output for the exact format.

To make the problem easier, we provided a portion of the code in the editor. You can either complete that code or write completely on your own.

**Here is my Code**

import java.util.*;

class Solution{

```
public static void main(String []argh){
    
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n=in.nextInt();
    in.nextLine();
    int []numbers =new int[n];
    String []names=new String[n];
    int real=0;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        String Tname=in.nextLine();
        int Tphone=in.nextInt();
        in.nextLine();
        numbers[i]=Tphone;
        names[i]=Tname;
        real++;
    }
    
    
    while(in.hasNext()){
        String s=in.nextLine();
        boolean isFound=false;
        int temp=0;
        for(int i=0;i<real;i++){
            if(names[i].equals(s)){
               isFound=true;
               temp=numbers[i];
               break;
            }
        }
        if(isFound){
            System.out.println(s+"="+temp);
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Not found");
        }  
    }
    
}
```

}

**And compiler message is**

Time limit exceeded
Your code did not execute within the time limits. Please optimize your code. For more information on execution time limits, refer to the environment page

Comment: I'll leave it up to you to figure it out, but did you consider using a [HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HashMap.html) for looking up entries instead of iterating over a (huge) array for each lookup?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for your timeout is caused by iterating over the entire list of numbers for every name. To solve your issue, you should look at something like `java.util.HashMap`.

And then to understand why this will (probably) work, you should look at what time complexities are in programming. To give a hint, searching for a single item in a list takes time proportional to the time of the list, while searching for an item in a `HashMap` requires constant time.

Comment: Ok, I will keep this in mind. Thanks a lot.